# Binding data to ComboBox WPF

Tags: wpf

I am newbie to WPF, and needs help to bind data into the ComboBox. The xaml file contains the tag below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SKAT.Postfordeler.Client.UI.View.ChooseInboxView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="42" d:DesignWidth="598">


<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox Name="_currentInbox" Width="180"  Margin="5" Height="22" DataContext="{Binding}"  />
        <Label Content="Et job kører allerede i denne indbakke (1500 ud af 1700 poster behandlet)" Name="_currentProcess"  Margin="5" Height="25" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

```
//Inbox class , this class was implemented in seperate project
namespace SKAT.Postfordeler.Shared.DataTypes
{
   [DataContract]
   public class Inbox
    {
       [DataMember]
       public String Id { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public String Folder { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public Rule Rules { get; set; }
    }
}

//This code is located in the controller, the Activate method will fire when the MainWindow was executed

 public void Activate()
        {
            var configuration = _configurationManager.GetConfiguration();// this method gets the xaml file settings

            _chooseInboxView.FillInboxes(configuration.Inboxes); // Inboxes data binds to combobox

        }
```

and in the View code behind, I created a method to bind the data which contains a type of list

```
public void FillInboxes(List<Inbox> inboxes)
{
   DataContext = inboxes;
}
```

But it won't works,Any help please?

Comment: How is `Inbox` implemented? Also, try binding `ItemsSource` of your ComboBox instead of `DataContext`.

Comment: Inbox is implemeted as a class which contains properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `Inbox` class consists of two properties (for simplicity), but there may be any number of them:

```
public class Inbox
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

You write a `DataTemplate`, for example:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InboxTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
            <TextBlock>:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Then correct your ComboBox declaration like:

```
<ComboBox Name="_currentInbox" Width="180"  Margin="5" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InboxTemplate}" />
```

Finally you set `DataContext` of your ComboBox to your `List<Inbox>`:

```
public void FillInboxes(List<Inbox> inboxes)
{
   _currentInbox.DataContext = inboxes;
}
```

**EDIT**: As you've asked for a simpler solution, you can just override `ToString()` method of your `Inbox` class:

```
protected override string ToString()
{
    return ID.ToString() + ":" + Text;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to add some additional codes in my xaml files, just a simple one. :) , This is also not working....

Comment: @user335160, I've tested the `DataTemplate` approach, and it worked for me. You might want to show what've you done, so I could see the problem. Check the edited version of my post, I've added a simpler solution.

Comment: Very nice. Excellent example + explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `DataContext={Binding}` you should have `ItemsSource={Binding}`.

The data context for any frameworkelement in the visual tree is by default `{Binding}`.

```
 <ComboBox Name="_currentInbox"
      SelectedItem="Hoved"
      Width="180"
      Margin="5"
      Height="22"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      ItemSource="{Binding}" />
```

Also for the combobox to display text of the items correctly I suppose you need `DisplayMemberPath` too. I assumed the property from `Inbox` class that you need to display is `Name`. Please replace with your relevant property name.

Comment: I tested this but I don't know why is not working. I paste the whole xaml codes for your reference.The data context has already a values, so there is something weird on this.

Comment: Please check your `Output` window. It must be showing some binding errors.

Answer (score 2):

If your Inbox class is like,

```
public class Inbox
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And if you do not want to change your xmal, the code behind method should be like this,

```
public void FillInboxes(List<Inbox> inboxes) 
    {
        _currentInbox.DisplayMemberPath = "Text"; // To display the 'Text' property in the combobox dropdown
        //_currentInbox.DisplayMemberPath = "ID"; // To display the 'ID' property in the combobox dropdown
        _currentInbox.DataContext = inboxes; 
    }
```

Comment: I tested this but I don't know why is not working. I paste the whole xaml codes for your reference.The data context has already a values, so there is something weird on this.

Comment: In that case, you can try, _currentInbox.DataContext = null, before assigning the DataContext to the combobox

Comment: @Debasis- still not working, argggggggg, I don't what happened on this, I created  a simple implementation and its working, but when I tried to apply it in my project it didin't work... wahhhh

Comment: Then do one thing, just remove DataContext="{Binding}" from your xaml and in code behind, instead of _currentInbox.DataContext = inboxes, try _currentInbox.ItemSource = inboxes

Comment: Hope your service is not returning an empty list ..!!